# Reading in messy csv data with data step

Tags: sas

```
timeOccur,timeReport,location,details,disposition
01/02/2021 11:20 am,,Sports Complex Road,Incident:  PATROL ACTIVITY - Patrol Check<br /> CAD #:  21-01-02-000062,In Service
01/02/2021 11:20 am,,Corporation,Incident:  ALARM - Burglary Alarm<br /> CAD #:  21-01-02-000063,Verified Entry/Field Interview
01/02/2021 10:20 am,,Grand Avenue Parking Structure,Incident:  PATROL ACTIVITY - Patrol Check<br /> CAD #:  21-01-02-000061,In Service
12/30/2020 11:02 pm,12/30/2020 11:02 pm - 12/30/2020 11:50 pm,Canyon Circle Parking Structure,Incident:  TRAFFIC COLLISION - Traffic Collision/Unknown Injury // ALCOHOL - Possession of false identification // TRAFFIC-ALCOHOL - DUI Alcohol // TRAFFIC - ALCOHOL - DUI >.08%<br /> Report #:  20074,Arrest
```

Need Help reading in this data.

```
Data CP_Crime;
    infile '/home/u60629206/SAS330_Handouts/Crime Scrape 01022021.csv' DLM = ',' DSD firstobs=2  MISSOVER;
    input  Time_Occur anydtdtm19. Time_Report anydtdtm19. Location :$60. Details :$150. Disposition $35.;
run;
```

I am unsure how to read the time report, when it gives me a range like that, not looking to format it so what the base sas returns is fine as generated in the time occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Treat `Time_Report` as as a character string, then convert each datetime within the string to a SAS datetime. Since both datetimes are separated by a `-`, we can use the `scan` function to read each one and convert them to SAS datetimes.

```
Data CP_Crime;      
    infile '/home/u60629206/SAS330_Handouts/Crime Scrape 01022021.csv' firstobs=2 DLM = ',' DSD  MISSOVER;

    input Time_Occur:anydtdtm19. Time_Report:$50. Location :$60. Details :$150. Disposition $35.;

    Time_Report_Start = input(scan(time_report, 1, '-'), anydtdtm.);
    Time_Report_End   = input(scan(time_report, 2, '-'), anydtdtm.);

    format Time_Occur
           Time_Report_Start
           Time_Report_End   mdyampm.
    ;

    drop time_report;
run;
```

Output:

```
Time_Occur            Time_Report_Start      Time_Report_End        Location                          ...
1/2/2021 11:20 AM     .                      .                      Sports Complex Road               ...
1/2/2021 11:20 AM     .                      .                      Corporation                       ...
1/2/2021 10:20 AM     .                      .                      Grand Avenue Parking Structure    ...
12/30/2020 11:02 PM   12/30/2020 11:02 PM    12/30/2020 11:50 PM    Canyon Circle Parking Structure   ...
```